# Getting Cannot Use Import Statement outside module when deploying React App on Server

Tags: reactjs, deployment

So I am trying to deploy my react app on a remote server.
I have uploaded both my build and .htaccess on the server
But when I run the website, I just get a blank screen.

The console log gives me the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at App.js:1:1)
> index.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at index.js:1:1)

I tried using "type":"module" on my package.json file but ended getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sorry about that, that was an error on my part when making the post